# How to use the computer keyboard with the emulator

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, keyboard, windows-phone, emulation

I want to use my computer keyboard instead of emulator keyboard SO,

> please tell me "How to use the computer keyboard with the emulator" ??

*I have also tried " **PAGE UP key.**" Option  But it's does not help me.*

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OOPS!

*I have found my answer now*

**When I Press the PAUSE/BREAK key.It's working now.**

I have found some more key words on this [MSDN Website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff754352%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

i use "page down" to use the laptop/pc keyboard in the Emulator. it works perfectly fine

Comment: But am using windows 8 . But that can't work for me. but working with `PAUSE/BREAK key.`